# Compute $P \{X \leq t < X+Y \}$ for $X$ and $Y$ exponential

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent exponential random variables with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively.

> **For a given $t>0$ find $P \{X \leq t < X+Y \}$**

I can find the joint PDF and the PDF of $X+Y$ but for some reason I am having a mental block on how to use them to find this probability. Any hints or solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need the PDF of $X+Y$.

Secondly, the joint PDF is just the product of PDF, by independence.

i.e. $F_{X,Y}(x,y) = \lambda\mu e^{-\lambda x-\mu y}1_{\{x>0,y>0\}}$

$P(X\leq t\leq X+Y) = E(1_{\{X\leq t\leq X+Y\}}) = E(1_{\{X\leq t\leq X+Y\}}|X)= E(E(1_{\{X\leq t\}}1_{\{t\leq X+Y\}}|X))=E(1_{\{X\leq t\}}E(1_{\{t\leq X+Y\}}|X))=\int^t_0(\int_{t-x}^\infty\mu e^{-\mu y}\text{d}y)\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\text{d}x$

Comment: It seems that your bounds on $Y$ are wrong. Should it not be $\int_0^t \int_{t-x}^{\infty} f(x,y)dydx$?

Comment: @mtiano yes, sorry to mislead you, we need $\{Y\geq t-X\}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: Find the joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, you said you can do this.

Hint 2: Identify the region on the xy-plane that you need to integrate over. Express it as a double integral. Then integrate.