# What is notation "$1_{\text{something}}$"? eg, $E(1_{\{X\leq t\leq X+Y\}}) $

Tags: measure-theory, notation, expected-value

In this mathStackExchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640655/compute-p-x-leq-t-xy-for-x-and-y-exponential?rq=1), use notation $E(1_{\{X\leq t\leq X+Y\}}) $. What is this notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of an event (set). Here,
$$
1_{\{X\leq t\leq X+Y\}} = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } X\leq t\leq X+Y\\
0 &\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$